# How to get all rows in table which it's contains other row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, my English not well.
I have a table:

```
ID            Name            Container

1             A               0
2             B               0
3             A1              1
4             A2              1
5             B1              2
6             B2              2
7             B11             5
```

Can i get all value as:

```
A
B
A.A1
A.A2
B.B1
B.B2
B.B1.B11
```

Thank for all reply

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Where are `B2` and `A2` in your output?

Comment: thank your reply. I want get all (include A.A2 and B.B2)

Comment: You're using SQL2012? You'll probably want to use a Common Table Expression. This help? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: thanks perterm & Chris Camaratta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE for that

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, CAST(name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) name, container 
    FROM Table1 
   WHERE container = 0
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, CAST(p.name + '.' + t.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)), t.container
    FROM Table1 t JOIN cte p
      ON p.id = t.container
)
SELECT name 
  FROM cte 
 ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
|     NAME |
------------
|        A |
|        B |
|     A.A1 |
|     A.A2 |
|     B.B1 |
|     B.B2 |
| B.B1.B11 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e48a/18)** demo